# jQuery - Given an animated Background-Image - How to keep the position on page reload?

Tags: jquery

I have a background image scroll on a DOM element. This works great, but when the user clicks a link to load a new page, the background image scrolling starts back at its original position...

Any clever way of making this appear more continuous so it's not jumpy? I thought about a cookie, but was concerned that would be writing much to frequently and could crash the browser is it's animating constantly.

Thanks

Comment: Any chance of seeing the webpage?  Not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you only need the information about the position if the page changes, it should be sufficient if you write the cookie only if the onunload-event of the window fires.

Answer (score 0):

How about only write the cookie when a link is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You could only update the cookie every five seconds, and in the `unload` event.

However, I don't think there's anything wrong with updating it more frequently; try it.